# select multiple attribute values in xslt

Tags: xslt

When I try to write a template with match I am not getting correct results.

Input :

```
<row>
   <entry align="left" nameend="8" namest="1" valign="top">
      <p type="Table Title">TABLE 12.  ELECTRICITY GENERATION
         (BILLION kW<tps:c type="_Table Light Blue grid ALL">·</c>h) IN ALTERNATIVE
      SCENARIOS</p>
   </tps:entry>
   <entry align="left" nameend="8" namest="1" valign="top">
      <p type="Table Title">TABLE 12.  ELECTRICITY GENERATION
         (BILLION kW<tps:c type="_Table Blue grid ALL">·</c>h) IN ALTERNATIVE
      SCENARIOS</p>
   </tps:entry>
</row>
```

Used code :

```
<xsl:template match="entry/p/c[@type != ('_Table Blue grid ALL' , '_Table Light Blue grid ALL' , '_Table Light Blue')]
```

I want to select `c` nodes where mentioned attribute values don't contain(not equal). But every `c` nodes are selected when I used `Used code`. How can I resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current expression will return true if the `c` value is not equal to just one of the selected values, not all of them, so effectively it will always be true.

You want to do this..

```
<xsl:template match="entry/p/c[not(@type = ('_Table Blue grid ALL' , '_Table Light Blue grid ALL' , '_Table Light Blue'))]" />
```

Do note this assumes you accounted for namespaces (with `xpath-default-namespace` perhaps)?